# Deploying with capistrano does ignore group setting

Tags: rvm, capistrano, chmod, rvm-capistrano

In my deploy-file I set the group to www-data:

```
set :user,            "root"
set :group,           "www-data"
```

so when using cap:setup I expected capistrano to chown the folders with root:www-data

But all folders and files are root:root.

Any ideas where this problem could come from?

Information: I'm Using system-wide-rvm.

Comment: This is a pretty bad practice to deploy as root, I suggest to create a user and deploy with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as for my understanding you should do it manually, what setup does is to
use the user to login, not to set the rights to directory.

I have found no group setting for capistrano, maybe you were using some extensions for it?

What you could do to change it could be:

```
after "deploy:setup", :setup_group
task :setup_group do
  run "chown -R :#{group} #{deploy_to} && chmod -R g+s #{deploy_to}"
end
```

But in first place you should not use **root** for deployment, as @Julian mentions in comment better practice is to use separate user for this task and set his group to proper group, then it will not require the above task and will work automatically.

Comment: Don't know why it's not working anymore, but this helps, THX. Working on the change to non-root-deployment but this offers a lot new problems

Comment: God, I was thoughtlessly using `set :group` for years! Never noticed, because usually my username and group are the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Just chiming in: there is *no mention of :group in Capistrano source code whatsoever*. I suppose it's a cargo cult option. And the :user option is only used for the SSH connection.

As to your question, directories and files that Capistrano creates are created with the default permissions, it never `chown`s them in any way; if you're deploying as `root` then they will belong to `root:root`.

Answer (score 2):

Better than fixing an issue is not having it in the first place:

1. First, create another user to deploy with ([as Julien suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177054/341929#comment14671201_11177054)).
   Say we call him `deployer`.
2. Then use him for the SSH connection
   `set :user, 'deployer'`
3. Lastly, we don't want to be use `sudo`, so turn it off by adding
   `set :use_sudo, false`
   to your `deploy.rb`.

Comment: When I do this, apache can't read the files since it's running under a different user/group to the deployer user. If I then manually chown -R to the webserver user, the site works. Any suggestions?

Comment: @joshua.paling What about adding the deployer to the www-data group?  This worked for me.  (Ubuntu:  ```sudo adduser deployer www-data```)