# How to setup a server for deployment and to do a cold deploy with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

What is the proper way to `deploy:setup` and to do a cold deploy with Capistrano?

Using

- [this `deploy.rb`](https://gist.github.com/mariusbutuc/5059868)
- Capistrano v2.14.2
- Vagrant to virtualize my server,

this is my scenario:

1. when running `deploy:setup`, Capistrano makes use of root privileges to prepare the directory structure for deployment:

   ```
   $ cap deploy:setup
     * 2013-02-28 14:50:21 executing `deploy:setup'
     * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /home/vagrant/example /home/vagrant/example/releases /home/vagrant/example/shared /home/vagrant/example/shared/system /home/vagrant/example/shared/log /home/vagrant/example/shared/pids"
       servers: ["example.com"]
       [example.com] executing command
       command finished in 29ms
     * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' chmod g+w /home/vagrant/example /home/vagrant/example/releases /home/vagrant/example/shared /home/vagrant/example/shared/system /home/vagrant/example/shared/log /home/vagrant/example/shared/pids"
       servers: ["example.com"]
       [example.com] executing command
       command finished in 11ms
   ```
2. yet upon `deploy:cold` Capistrano attempts to checkout (from git in this case) and write as the `vagrant` user – the user specified in `deploy.rb`:

   ```
   $ cap deploy:cold
     * 2013-02-28 14:50:47 executing `deploy:cold'
     * 2013-02-28 14:50:47 executing `deploy:update'
    ** transaction: start
     * 2013-02-28 14:50:47 executing `deploy:update_code'
       updating the cached checkout on all servers
       executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:mariusbutuc/realtime-faye.git master"
       command finished in 2360ms
     * executing "if [ -d /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard a7c05516bc31c2c18f89057c02f84bfad83a6b59 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:mariusbutuc/realtime-faye.git /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy a7c05516bc31c2c18f89057c02f84bfad83a6b59; fi"
       servers: ["example.com"]
       [example.com] executing command
    ** [example.com :: out] fatal: could not create work tree dir '/home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy'.: Permission denied
       command finished in 26ms
   *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
     * executing "rm -rf /home/vagrant/example/releases/20130228195049; true"
       servers: ["example.com"]
       [example.com] executing command
       command finished in 7ms
   failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard a7c05516bc31c2c18f89057c02f84bfad83a6b59 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:mariusbutuc/realtime-faye.git /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/vagrant/example/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy a7c05516bc31c2c18f89057c02f84bfad83a6b59; fi'" on example.com
   ```
3. Of course, the `deploy:check` report bares no surprises: the `vagrant` user cannot write in the directories created during `deploy:setup` since the two users belong to different groups – `root:root` versus `vagrant:vagrant`:

   ```
   $ cap deploy:check
     [...]
   The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
   --> You do not have permissions to write to `/home/vagrant/example'. (example.com)
   --> You do not have permissions to write to `/home/vagrant/example/releases'. (example.com)
   --> `/home/vagrant/example/shared' is not writable (example.com)
   ```

What is the reasoning behind this, and what prerequisite is not satisfied yet so the deployment passes this issue?

Comment: and you don't want to manually change the permissions?

Comment: I've had exactly this same problem... I don't understand why the directories are created as the root user instead of as the user specified in the `deploy.rb` file. I'm assuming it's a bug? I end up just SSH-ing in and changing the permissions manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deploy:setup` task probably should not be using `sudo` to create the app directory, since that is likely causing it to be owned by `root`.

You can turn that off in your `deploy.rb` file with:

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, and it's a lot more elegant than my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are [no group setting in Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231528/341929) my workaround is to extend such a setting, for example:

```
set :user,  'vagrant'
set :group, 'vagrant'
```

and then create a task to "fix" the ownership after running `deploy:setup`:

```
after "deploy:setup", :setup_ownership
task :setup_ownership do
  run "#{sudo} chown -R #{user}:#{group} #{deploy_to} && chmod -R g+s #{deploy_to}"
end
```

But the only thing better than fixing an issue is not having it in the first place, so [Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196358/341929) is both wiser and more elegant.